# TSQL return multiple column for each row of data based on different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grafana

I have a table with `[MemoryValue],[ServerName],[ServerType],[CreateDate]`.
I want to display in Grafana, MemoryValue for each combination of ServerName and ServerType. Basically have different graphs for each ServerName and ServerType combination. E.g.

```
MemoryValue ServerName  ServerType
15757746    bob         type1   
182         bob         type2   
8           bob         type3
15757746    bob2        type1   
182         bob2        type2   
8           bob2        type3
```

I want to have 6 graphs per ServerName+ServerType where it displays the MemoryValue.

When I try

```
select MemoryValue ,  CreateDate  as time
    from table
    group by ServerName, ServerType
```

it has the error of "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.". When I try adding MemoryValue to GROUP BY the graph doesn't reflect what I want and it shows a single graph as oppose to multiple.

I want MemoryValue per CreateDate separated by each ServerName and ServerType to look something like this
[image: Sample graph]

Comment: Edit the question with your desired outcome.

Comment: When aggregating.. you can only have columns that are either participating in the group by or... they have to be wrapped in an aggregate function (ie. sum, min, max, count, etc) in the SELECT clause.

Comment: I guess I can't use GROUP BY then. How can I  MemoryValue per CreateDate separated by each ServerName and ServerType to look like the graph above

Comment: Some meaningful sample data and your desired output (from the query, not a picture of a graph) would go a long way toward helping us help you. There are some good suggestions and tools here: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
select MAX(MemoryValue) as mem ,  MAX(CreateDate)  as time
    from table
    group by ServerName, ServerType
```

Change MAX to whatever aggregate you want (AVG, SUM, etc)

Comment: I want the memory value per time as well. MAX query won't display memory value per time.  [This is what it looks like](https://imgur.com/a/35dwbmz)

Comment: then group by MemoryValue as well and only aggregate the CreateDate column

Answer (score 0):

Is this sort of what you're looking for? STRING_AGG was introduced in SQL Server 2017.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp (
    MemoryValue INT,
    ServerName VARCHAR(100),
    ServerType VARCHAR(100)
)
GO
INSERT INTO #Tmp (MemoryValue,ServerName,ServerType)
VALUES (15757746,'bob','type1'),(182,'bob','type2'),(8,'bob','type3'),(15757746,'bob2','type1'),(182,'bob2','type2'),(8,'bob2','type3')
GO

SELECT ServerType, string_agg(ServerName,','), MAX(MemoryValue)
FROM #Tmp
GROUP BY ServerType
GO
```